# Python tests. Patch method from library in venv

Tags: python, django, testing, mocking

I know how to patch my methods:

```
@patch('common.connections.upload_image')
def test_upload(self, mocked_upload_image):
    mocked_upload_image.return_value = 'Mocked url'
```

This will patch my method `upload_image` in module `connections` in folder `common` (I am using Django, folder `common` lies in root).

But I want to patch serializer from Django Rest framework, which lies in `venv.lib.python2.7.site-packages.rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer.is_valid`

So I tried:

```
@patch('venv.lib.python2.7.site-packages.rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer.is_valid')
def test_upload(self, mocked_is_valid):
    mocked_is_valid.return_value = True # this doesn't work
```

But it doesn't work. Says `ImportError: No module named venv`.
My `venv` folder lies in the same folder, where the above mentioned `common` lies.

**So how to patch this library method then?**

Comment: You can patch it from rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer.is_valid and you can leave the path from your virtualenv to the library out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `@patch('rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer.is_valid')`

Comment: Thanks, that worked, now don't know how to avoid `AssertionError: You must call .is_valid() before accessing .validated_data.`